# Doing the equivalent of "adb pull", but initiated from the Android device, not via adb

Tags: adb, file-management

I have a rooted Oreo Android device, and I can use "adb pull" from my linux machine to retrieve copies of files and directories from my device.

However, I want to get a full copy of each and every file and directory on my device, starting from the root filesystem. I know I have to do "adb root" in order to allow this to happen, but when I do so, I get the following error ...

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

So what I'd like to do, if possible, is to get this data onto my linux machine in the opposite manner: *i.e.*, to be su'ed on my android device, and from that device, to cause a complete recursive copy of everything from root on down to somehow be sent out to my linux machine.

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have an SD card with enough free space to hold all those data? Then the much easier approach would be to copy (or `tar cf`) the files on-device to the SD card, and then pull them from there. Or, if you have a custom recovery like TWRP installed, simply perform a backup with it (also results in tar files).

Comment: I do have a large sd card and tried the `tar cf` approach, but I ran into permissions problems even though I set selinux to "permissive". It got about 10 percent into the copy and failed with a permission error. But the TWRP backup idea worked for me. I didn't realize that the files in the backup directory  are tar files. So that's the answer.

Comment: Yupp – sometimes the easiest things are the hardest to find :) Thanks for self-answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **izzy**, above, I realized that I can copy the TWRP backup directory to my linux machine and de-tar the files contained in the backup. I didn't realize that they were tar files.

This is the solution.